# Is there any way to change the original image size of smart object, without reflecting the size of smart object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Basically, for testing the design, I first use low resolution images. I convert theme to smart objects. Then I import the smart object to After effects for further work. But once design is done, I need HD images. I need to replace those low resolution images with HD images.

Let me help you understand by giving an example:

I have 1000x1000 px image. I've converted it to smart object and pasted in my main PSD document. And resized it to 500x500px.

Now, after all things are done, finally I need to replace the 1000x1000px image with 3000x3000px image.

There is a way for this: Resize the 1000px image to 3000px. Now the canvas is large. Paste the HD image there. **But this has a problem**.

Now the smart object which was of 500x500px, is bigger, which will break all things in After effects in main PSD.

Is there any way to do this without changing smart object size?

Comment: isn't it pretty obvious that AE only records values such as scales; assume you've set 50% scale of smart object at keyframe 1; so in first case the size was 250px and once you change 1000px to 3000px it's 750px! so as far as I think this can't be avoided but if you want animations for android app (lottie) then you can just scale it after exporting :)

Comment: I don't have experience with After Effects, but I often do a similar thing with images placed in InDesign. I design with an image which I later realize needs to be scaled up. I can then resize by *changing the ppi* instead of *scaling to a percentage*. InDesign then understands that the *physical size* must be unchanged. Maybe After Effects works in a similar way?

Comment: @Wolff @ Design Phoenix actually the problem has nothing to do with After Effects. I just mentioned it to understand problem. Further I don't know much about that. And yes, if physical size remains unchanged of smart object and PPI of original image gets changed, problem will be solved. But it doesn't happen currently in Photoshop.

Comment: @Vikas what do you mean by *it doesn't happen currently in Photoshop* because you can change ppi by resampling it (ctrl+alt+i)

Comment: @DesignPhoenix yes. When I do this, the image size changes, but it also changes the size of smart object. Which affects the size of elements of design. I want to affect the *quality* of design.

Comment: there's a shorthand trick to do that: open image resize dialog - change PPI (this will change your size too but don't worry) - once you changed ppi change size again in width and height tab and you can see your ppi will stay same :D